# Building documents with latexmk: how to do this?

Tags: latexmk

I want to use `latexmk` to build my documents, in order to stop compiling different things all the time just to get an updated document. However, I have no clue how to do this. I am running `OS-X 10.9.4.`

I have had `latexmk` installed from TeX Live Utility. I have noticed that I can, in TeXstudio, set my compiler to be latexmk.

My question is basically, "What do I do, and how to I set it all up?". I have read about `Makefiles`, of which I know nothing. I have read `latexmk`'s user's manual, but it just lists a whole lot of options to a command I do not understand.

I have found no beginner's guide, how-to's, or anything similar on the web that might help me set this up. Please do not underestimate the statement of how little I know about this; however, I am very eager to learn!

Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: First, see [Collins' documentation](http://users.phys.psu.edu/~collins/software/latexmk-jcc/latexmk-439.txt). Next, in a terminal, `cd` to the folder where you have `somefile.tex`, and try `latexmk -pdf somefile` (without the .tex). You'll end up with a PDF output from that file. By default, `latexmk` will also run `bibtex` as needed. Past that, you'll need a more specific question and MWE where something fails.